# time measure in fact table (SSAS)

Tags: ssas, aggregation, measure

I have a time measure with data type time(7) in SQL Server 2008 R2, but in ssas this type changed to WChar. This measure represents time of Entry-Exit of Persens, and I want do Aggregation (Sum) on it and Average of Entry-Exit.

Could someone suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the field to an int / seconds in your etl.  Store as int in your cube (you probably want to hide this).

Create calculated measure for averages etc in ssas.  You can also use calculated measures method for converting back to a more user friendly hours or mins.

Comment: Thank You Daryl.
I want create a chart in Excel by this calculated measure (test). I use from this calculation.But this Calculated measure is not showing in Chart in Excel.( Maybe type of it is not known for Excel.)
test=
iif([Measures].[EntryExit] = 0, null, Format(Int([Measures].[EntryExit]/86400), "0:") +
Format( TimeSerial(0, 0, [Measures].[EntryExit] - (Int([Measures].[EntryExit]/86400) * 86400)),"HH:mm" ) )
-------
[Measures].[EntryExit] is a calculated measure (Average of EntryExit) Can you help me please?

Comment: You should really add a comment to the existing answer or edit your question, not create a second answer. Your calculated measure should work fine.  Have you set visible to true (on calc measure) and refreshed your cube and excel?